Asking permission of Imam Before Entering Dar Al Harb
Sorry for asking hypothetical question but is it compulsory that a Muslim must seek permission of Imam before travelling to Dar Al Harb even if Ahlul Harb gives Aman to the Muslim for trade?
The quote below might be discussing other issue but first few line raise this question in my mind. Please clarify
[فَصْلٌ دَخَلَ قَوْمٌ لَا مَنَعَةَ لَهُمْ دَارَ الْحَرْبِ بِغَيْرِ إذْنِ الْإِمَامِ فَغَنِمُوا]
فَصْلٌ: إذَا دَخَلَ قَوْمٌ لَا مَنَعَةَ لَهُمْ دَارَ الْحَرْبِ، بِغَيْرِ إذْنِ الْإِمَامِ، فَغَنِمُوا، فَعَنْ أَحْمَدَ فِيهِ ثَلَاثُ رِوَايَاتٍ إحْدَاهُنَّ، أَنَّ غَنِيمَتَهُمْ كَغَنِيمَةِ غَيْرِهِمْ، يُخَمِّسُهُ الْإِمَامُ، وَيَقْسِمُ بَاقِيه بَيْنَهُمْ. وَهَذَا قَوْلُ أَكْثَرِ أَهْلِ الْعِلْمِ، مِنْهُمْ الشَّافِعِيُّ؛ لِعُمُومِ قَوْلِهِ سُبْحَانَهُ: {وَاعْلَمُوا أَنَّمَا غَنِمْتُمْ مِنْ شَيْءٍ فَأَنَّ لِلَّهِ خُمُسَهُ} [الأنفال: 41] . الْآيَةَ.
وَالْقِيَاسُ عَلَى مَا إذَا دَخَلُوا بِإِذْنِ الْإِمَامِ. وَالثَّانِيَةُ، هُوَ لَهُمْ مِنْ غَيْرِ أَنْ يُخَمَّسَ. وَهُوَ قَوْلُ أَبِي حَنِيفَةَ؛ لِأَنَّهُ اكْتِسَابٌ مُبَاحٌ مِنْ غَيْرِ جِهَادٍ، فَكَانَ لَهُمْ أَشْبَهَ الِاحْتِطَابَ، فَإِنَّ الْجِهَادَ إنَّمَا يَكُونُ بِإِذْنِ الْإِمَامِ، أَوْ مِنْ طَائِفَةٍ لَهُمْ مَنَعَةٌ وَقُوَّةٌ، فَأَمَّا هَذَا فَتَلَصُّصٌ وَسَرِقَةٌ وَمُجَرَّدُ اكْتِسَابٍ.
وَالثَّالِثَةُ، أَنَّهُ لَا حَقَّ لَهُمْ فِيهِ. قَالَ أَحْمَدُ، فِي عَبْدٍ أَبَقَ إلَى الرُّومِ، ثُمَّ رَجَعَ وَمَعَهُ مَتَاعٌ: فَالْعَبْدُ لِمَوْلَاهُ، وَمَا مَعَهُ مِنْ الْمَتَاعِ وَالْمَالِ فَهُوَ لِلْمُسْلِمِينَ؛ لِأَنَّهُمْ عُصَاةٌ بِفِعْلِهِمْ، فَلَمْ يَكُنْ لَهُمْ فِيهِ حَقٌّ.
وَإِنْ كَانَتْ الطَّائِفَةُ ذَاتَ مَنَعَةٍ، غَزَوْا بِغَيْرِ إذْنِ الْإِمَامِ، فَفِيهِ رِوَايَتَانِ؛ إحْدَاهُمَا، لَا شَيْءَ لَهُمْ، وَهُوَ فَيْءٌ لِلْمُسْلِمِينَ. وَالثَّانِيَةُ، يُخَمَّسُ، وَالْبَاقِي لَهُمْ. وَهَذَا أَصَحُّ. وَوَجْهُ الرِّوَايَتَيْنِ مَا تَقَدَّمَ. وَيُخَرَّجُ فِيهِ وَجْهٌ كَالرِّوَايَةِ الثَّالِثَةِ، وَهُوَ أَنَّ الْجَمِيعَ لَهُمْ مِنْ غَيْرِ خُمْسٍ؛ لِكَوْنِهِ اكْتِسَابُ مُبَاحٍ مِنْ غَيْرِ جِهَادٍ.
Al Mughni
